# scrapyd pool_intervel to scheduler a spider

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I want to make my spider start every three hours.

I have a scrapy confinguration file located in `c:/scrapyd` folder.

I changed the `poll_interval` to `100`

the spider works, but it didn't repeat each 100 seconds.

how to do that please?

Comment: Did you manage to figure that out?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do a cron job that executes every three hours and performs a curl call to Scrapyd to schedule the job.